# Estimate aggregate count of SQL from previous queries?

Tags: sql, count, aggregate

[image]

Green dashed rectangle: previous known range query (i know its aggregate count)

Red rectangle: current unknown range query (i don't know its aggregate count)

Assuming a uniform data distribution, I should be able to estimate the count of objects in the red rectangle by knowing the count in the dashed green rectangle, just like this:

```
count_green_dashed_rec / area_green_dashed_rec = count_red_rec / area_red_rec
```

The area of both rectangles is computed by `= hight*width`

and I want to estimate: **count_red_rec**

Since everything is known, except **count_red_rec**, then we can compute it by:

```
count_red_rec = count_green_dashed_rec * area_red_rec / area_green_dashed_rec
```

Although, the computed value is never %100 correct, it is always off by small percentage, like %1-2

How to know that percentage of inaccuracy ?

Comment: Did you mean the actual inaccuracy or a computed inaccuracy?

Comment: You calculate the inaccuracy by getting the correct value and comparing it to the estimate.

Comment: @jbarker2160 a computed inaccuracy, not the actual one. For the actual inaccuracy, I'll have to execute the red_rec query and know its actual aggregate count. But I don't want to do that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I cannot get the correct value, since that involves calling the database, and I don't wanna do that.

Comment: @user1728624, then you'll have to know the variance of the data and you can use that to compute a 1-2% confidence range.

Comment: @jbarker2160 could you please explain more?

Comment: @user1728624, if you  can't use the actual value you have to calculate it based on a sample of similar data.  There is no way to know how inaccurate your data is without comparing to the actual results or estimating based on the inaccuracy of prior queries.